# SSH error: WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!

Tags: ssh, rsync, cygwin, ssh-keygen

I ran rsync (cygwin) and got this error. I think they changed the Red Hat Linux OS from version 5 to version 6, last night. Would that be the cause of this error message? What do I need to do to fix this? I remember, the sysadm ran a command called ssh-keygen I think on my computer after he set up cygwin. Do I re-run that and copy the file to the RH6 server?

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/xxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /home/xxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:2
RSA host key for xxxxx has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

Comment: remove line 2 of your know_hosts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you believe the host really did change its host key you can delete the old entry.  Since this one tells you the old entry is on line 2 you can do

`sed -i -e '2d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

to remove the old entry from you known hosts file

Comment: Thanks, the known_hosts was on my workstation. I ran the command you suggested from cygwin and it worked! When I ran the rsync batch file again, it said: The authenticity of host 'xxxxx (xxx.xx.xx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xxxxx,xxx.xx.xx.xx ' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
xxxxx@xxxxx's password:

Comment: Yup, now you have a new entry for that host in your known_hosts, so if it changes again you'll have to remove it again, though it will be on a different line next time.

Comment: The problem is that even though I added known_hosts locally, the remote server is still asking for the password. I think I need to copy a file over to the remote server?

Comment: http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html: I see I had to copy id_rsa.pub to .ssh/authorized_keys of the remote server